# Generator with slice assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, slice

Suppose I have a silly function, like FizzBuzz:

```
>>> def FizzBuzz(i):
...     if i % 15 == 0:
...         return "FB"
...     elif i % 3 == 0:
...         return "F"
...     elif i % 5 == 0:
...         return "B"
...     else:
...         return i
```

And a list:

```
>>> li=list(range(1,22))
>>> li
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Now if I do a generator expression applying that function to the list:

```
>>> ge=(FizzBuzz(x) for x in li)
>>> ge
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1063ca3a8>
```

I can turn that into a list (i.e., run the generator expression):

```
>>> list(ge)
[1, 2, 'F', 4, 'B', 'F', 7, 8, 'F', 'B', 11, 'F', 13, 14, 'FB', 16, 17, 'F', 19, 'B', 'F']
```

Now suppose I do a slice assignment rather than an assignment to a separate name:

```
>>> li=list(range(1,22))
>>> li[:]=(FizzBuzz(x) for x in li)
>>> li
[1, 2, 'F', 4, 'B', 'F', 7, 8, 'F', 'B', 11, 'F', 13, 14, 'FB', 16, 17, 'F', 19, 'B', 'F']
```

You can see that the generator expression is immediately executed.

Same with `map`:

```
>>> map(FizzBuzz, li)
<map object at 0x10640c358>
>>> li[:]=map(FizzBuzz, li)
>>> li
[1, 2, 'F', 4, 'B', 'F', 7, 8, 'F', 'B', 11, 'F', 13, 14, 'FB', 16, 17, 'F', 19, 'B', 'F']
```

Now suppose that `FizzBuzz` is not a silly function, but rather a function that takes a while and `li` is big enough that you want to do slice assignment.

Is there a way to defer the execution of the generator but still assign in place? (I do realize that I can just do `ge=(f(x) for x in big_list); big_list[:]=list(ge)` which is a workaround...)

Comment: `for index, val in enumerate(li): li[index] = FizzBuzz(val)`? But it's not really clear why you want this - if you need all of the values in a list at once, then surely you have to wait for the generator to be evaluated anyway?

Comment: You want inplace processing with a generator depending on original data and without extra memory used. No way))

Comment: I think you are overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, `(FizzBuzz(x) for x in li)` needs `li` to be still "intact" when it starts running, since it must loop over it and get the right items.

So where would you want to "assign in place" -- **what** place do you have in mind?

Assigning it to a variable independent of `li`, which you diss as "a workaround", is fine of course.

But **where** would you like to put it instead?!

Certainly not anywhere where it would trample on `li`'s contents until you're ready to run it, since we've already established that said contents must be intact when the generator starts running.

You could bind those contents with a `def`, e.g

```
def doge(savedli=list(li)):
    for x in savedli: yield FizzBuzz(x)
```

Now, `li[:]=doge` will wipe away `li`'s contents, superficially, but still keep them safely stashed away in `doge` (now set to `li[0]`), so later you could do `li[:] = doge()`.  But I don't see any advantage in this more contorted approach.

So if this answer is not satisfactory, please clarify in **what** place you want to "assign in place" a generator, respecting of course the need for the list's original contents to survive *some*where until the generator starts running.

Comment: I certainly did not mean to sound like `ge=(f(x) for x in big_list); big_list[:]=list(ge)` was somehow unacceptable or 'diss' in anyway! :-)  I am more asking this along the lines of trying to formulate in my own mind a workable rule of thumb. Working with Python for a while, I never really considered that a slice assignment would trigger the generator. One of the knuckle headed 'aha' moments I suppose...

Comment: @Pyson, point is that slice assignment requires a sequence on the RHS, so iteration on said RHS is forced by said slice assignment.  I still don't understand in **what** place you'd like to "assign in place" the yet-unexecuted generator.  `li[:] = [(FizzBuzz(x) for x in li)]` for example would do it -- but of course it would wipe out `li`'s contents (the very **point** of a slice assignment!) so by the time you're ready to expand the generator there's nothing left for said generator to usefully loop on -- those contents must be *preserved* until you start running the generator, of course!